# Error within tableView when swapping detailView for a different view

Tags: swift, function, uitableview, view, segue

I have the function

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let object = dailyAgenda[indexPath.row]
        if object == "Time Management" {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTimeManagement", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
        }}}
```

And the prepare for segue function

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = dailyAgenda[indexPath.row]
            var controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.textDescription = indepthDescript[indexPath.row]
        }}
    if segue.identifier == "showTimeManagement" {
        var controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! TimeManagement
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" when selecting the cell that performs the showTimeManagement segue. The error occurs on the "controller.textDescription = indepthDescript[indexPath.row]]" line within the showDetail segue. Why would it even be running this line in the first place and where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: sure that **indepthDescript** count is equal to the tableView's dataSource array if it's  not the one ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan but why would that matter if I'm not even calling the prepare function for the showDetail identifier. I'm calling it for the showTimeMangement, yet still get an error in the method of the showDetail.

Comment: Have you tried checking what object is to see if `[enter image description here][1]][1][indexPath.row]` is actually equal to `"Time Management"` like you think it is? That may be the first issue. The second is that you should add a check before accessing that index to make sure that array is large enough.

Comment: @kaylaGalway the enter image thing was an error and not part of my code, I've since edited my question. So dailyAgenda[indexPath.row] are the labels for each cell and the title of the detailView and indepthDescript is equal to an array of descriptions for the titles. I don't understand though if I'm clicking on a cell that should perform the TimeManagement segue and its giving me an error in the detailView Segue, I'm not even calling that viewController.

Comment: It would seem that when you are clicking that cell, `object == "Time Management"` is not true, so it is defaulting to the else statement. Try adding `print(object)` before the if statement and see what it shows as.

Comment: it prints only when I delete the controller.textdescription = indepthDescript[indexPath.row], so I know its its true except for that one line that is messing things up somehow